# While loop in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I have some little issues with syntax. I am used to C# and just started [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). I am trying to do a `while` loop when it loops through the items from a list. What is the syntax that I am doing wrong?

```
While oResponse.outputControl.Items(i) <> Nothing

    //Do something

End While
```

Comment: The problem is the <> Nothing part, try Is Nothing instead.

Comment: Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.ListItem and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

Comment: But Is is the opposite of your original code.  I would think you want the IsNot operator instead.

Comment: The Is allowed to to find IsNot I did not know the operators for vb I am used to C# so it was a stepping stone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget to increment your counter:

```
While oResponse.outputControl.Items(i) <> Nothing

    'Do something
    i += 1

End While
```

and if this is a reference type (you didn't say, but it probably is), you can't compare it to `Nothing` with the `<>` operator:

```
While oResponse.outputControl.Items(i) IsNot Nothing

    'Do something
    i += 1

End While
```

But maybe what you really want is a For Each loop:

```
For Each Item In oResponse.outputControl.Items
    'Do Something
Next Item
```

And one more thing: what's with the hungarian wart in the `oResponse` variable? That style is no longer recommended, and Microsoft now even specifically recommends against it. VB.Net also has a feature called "Default properties" that just might make this even simpler. Pulling it all together (now including the ListItem type from your comment above):

```
For Each Item As ListItem In Response.outputControl
    'Do Something
Next Item
```

Comment: "And one more thing: what's with the hungarian wart in the oResponse variable?" Not my code. I just started working on the code yesterday. Right now I am focusing on functionality and then going back to change all that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
While oResponse.outputControl.Items(i) Is Nothing

    'do something

End While
```

You could also do this if you wanted to be particularly old school:

```
Do

    'do something

Loop Until Not oResponse.outputControl.Items(i) Is Nothing
```